# Bash - How to extract JSON from a web page?

Tags: json, bash

I'm trying to extract JSON from this URL: [here](https://www.lazada.co.id/-i160040703-s181911730.html?spm=a2o4j.order_details.details_title.1.52ec6664luQAQs&urlFlag=true&mp=1)

The output that I want is like this https://pastebin.com/BVzUrk6s .Sorry I can't paste it here because of the StackOverFlow character limit.

Here is what I have tried:

```
curl 'https://www.lazada.co.id/-i160040703-s181911730.html?spm=a2o4j.order_details.details_title.1.52ec6664luQAQs&urlFlag=true&mp=1' | grep -Poz '(?<=app.run\()(.*\n)*.*(?=\);)'
```

But that command still doesn't extract the JSON data. How do I solve this ? I want to use a pure bash script without installing any programs to do this if possible.

Comment: Use the `jq` (json query) package. Don't try and parse json with bash alone. There are may posts on this site about jq.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin did you even read the question ? The JSON is mixed with HTML that's why I can't use `jq` out the box

Comment: You need to learn how to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, pure `bash` is not capable of handling JSON or HTML correctly, short of writing your own parsers. Install the right tools for the jobs you need to do.

Comment: This is actual JavaScript, not just JSON

Answer (score 0):

It's a Bad Idea (TM) to attempt JSON parsing this way.

It seems like a Good Idea (TM) to find out what is possible regardless.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function parseUrl() {
    local url=$1
    echo '"childCategories": ['
    curl --silent ${url} \
        | awk '/<script type="text" class=J_data/ { show=1 } show; /<\/script>/ { show=0 }' \
        | egrep -v "script" \
        | sed -e 's/]//g' -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/{"childCategoryName":"","childCategoryUrl":""},//g' -e 's/}$/},/g' \
        | sed -e 's/,{/,\'$'\n{/g' -e 's/^[ ]*//g' -e 's/{/    {/g' \
        | sed -e 's/childCategoryName/name/g' -e 's/childCategoryUrl/url/g'
    echo ' ]'
}

parseUrl 'https://www.lazada.co.id/-i160040703-s181911730.html?spm=a2o4j.order_details.details_title.1.52ec6664luQAQs&urlFlag=true&mp=1' \
    | tee /tmp/extracted.json
```

So there you go: curl, awk, egrep, sed. Use at your own risk.

1. Code like this isn't extensible, meaning you can't extract nested JSON easily.
2. It is quite brittle, meaning if someone changes the layout or even CSS, it's bye-bye data extraction.